# Populating ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Hello i am having problem on populating the list view on Fragment
the following is my fragment.class

```
package com.example.fred.p;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         String[] game = { "Android", "iOS", "window" };
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView(), getContext() , android.R.layout.p_g, game);
         getListView(), setAdapter(adapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

}
```

The xml file for the fragment is as follows. i would like to populate only three
items in the view can someone please help me this is the code that i have written
Thank you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fred.p.MainFragment">




    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/p_adds"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/p_g"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">



    </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace or is there any compilation error

Comment: The Error is it can't find the getListView and p_g(which is the id of the list view in the xml file) @DJphy

Comment: create the method getListView()

Comment: Need help on that @DJphy

Comment: ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.theLayoutForEachRow, R.id.theTextViewOnTheRow, yourGameArray);

Comment: u can find a lot of examples on setting up list view using array adapter. u should be able to find one.. Let me know if u cant; i'll post one here

Comment: please post it Thanks @DJphy

Answer (score 0):

try to this...

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
           ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.p_g);
           String[] game = { "Android", "iOS", "window" };

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, game);
             lv.setAdapter(adapter);


            return view
        }
```

Comment: I am getting the error that it cannot find the getListView() and p_g(which is the id of the list view).

Comment: R.id.text1  textview defined in android.R.alyout.simple_list_item_1

Answer (score 0):

First Thing change array adapter declaration as below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  android.R.layout.p_g,  game);
```

Second thing as you have extend fragment therefore you can't use getListView() method,
as for that you need to extends ListActivity.

So better is take one ListView object and assign it here.

Declare like:

```
ListView lstData;
```

Then in viewCreated method initialise lstData like:

```
lstData = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_g);
```

Then after array adapter declaration set adapter as below:

```
lstData.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello @Vickyexpert it returns a null

Comment: Declare ArrayAdapter Properly as below

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, game);

Answer (score 0):

Place this list view where ever u want to display; for eg: u want to display the list view in **activity_main_layout**; i'll show here;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="150dp" //u can have ur own width
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then define a layout for your rows in the list view; i'll show how to place a texview in the list view row (**file name: row_layout.xml**):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="saggsg"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In you main activity do this in **oncreate**:

```
String[] game = new String[] { "Android", "iOS", "window" };    
    ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    gameList.addAll( Arrays.asList(game) );
    ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_layout,R.id.rowTextView, gameList);
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView .setAdapter(myAdapter );
```

//You can even add a onItemClickListener() to this listview; enjoy

Comment: Thank you but listItem is not defined @Djphy

Comment: ur list items are android, ios and window

Comment: check now it must be the listview.. what to do we dont have a IDE here to check my variables.. hahahaa

Comment: hahahahah okay @DJphy this thing hahha now findViewById cannot be resolved hahah

Comment: make sure the onCreate code is the activity. Don't be so dumb, i think then u shouldn't be a developer. change ur job/ur current hobby.. Hahaahaa

Comment: wait; i just a fragment; inflate the layout in which u have the list view;like this **View tempView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_layout, container, false)**//here activity_main_layout holds the list view.. Then use **tempView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);**... u can return the same tempView

Comment: Cheers!! .. i didn't see that intially

Comment: `ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_layout,R.id.rowTextView, gameList);` gives me mismatch error

Comment: i think thats a jdk issue; if the jdk is less that 7 u need to mention the type of the list.. try this **ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_layout,R.id.rowTextView, gameList);** //the IDE must have prompted u.

Comment: Now its running but there is not list of items duuuh

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' `on a null object reference thats what i am getting @DJphy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106343/discussion-between-djphy-and-user3551487).